# Select All checkbox Angular material 5 | Gmail style if selecting individual it will also select

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I need to create a select all functionality in angular material, I am sharing code below which is partially working.

```
<section *ngFor="let ing of pizzaIng; let i = index" class="example-section">
  <mat-checkbox (change)="selectChildren()"
     [(ngModel)]="ing.checked">
    {{ing.name}}
  </mat-checkbox>
</section>
  <mat-checkbox (change)="updateCheck()"
      class="example-margin"
      [(ngModel)]="selectAll">
    Select All
  </mat-checkbox>
```

**.ts file**

```
export class CheckboxConfigurableExample {
    pizzaIng: any;
    selectAll = false;

    constructor() {
        this.pizzaIng = [{
                name: "Pepperoni",
                checked: false
            },
            {
                name: "Sasuage",
                checked: true
            },
            {
                name: "Mushrooms",
                checked: false
            }
        ];
    }


    selectChildren() {

        for (var i = 0; i < this.pizzaIng.length; i++) {
            if (this.pizzaIng[i].checked === true) {
                return this.selectAll = true;
            } else {
                return this.selectAll = false;
            }

        }
    }




    updateCheck() {
        console.log(this.selectAll);
        if (this.selectAll === true) {
            this.pizzaIng.map((pizza) => {
                pizza.checked = true;
            });

        } else {
            this.pizzaIng.map((pizza) => {
                pizza.checked = false;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

select all/deselect is working but the individual selection is not working properly, if selected the first one it is selecting the select all but it should work when selected all individual, Please help.

Comment: `updateCheck` is this for individual checkboxes when checked/unchecked manually it's not turning parent checkbox(selectAll/UnSelectedAll) is that right ?

Comment: update check is for all the checkbox select/deselect and selectChildren will check the each individual selection and update the select all when all are selected

Comment: your approach is odd you should have `*ngFor` on children only. you can fix the above mentioned issue by using $.grep and check if there is any unchecked based on that turn selectAll flag (true/false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your selectchildren to this, using [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) will check all the checkboxes are checked, and it should work fine. You already have a checked property which has the values as checked or not, you can check if all entries are checked then youc an enable the selectAll, else disable it.

```
  selectChildren() {    
    if (this.pizzaIng.every(a => a.checked)) {
      this.selectAll = true;
    } else {
      this.selectAll = false;
    }
  }
```

Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-checkbox-demo-a4u7c7)

Answer (score 1):

### HTML

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
<ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="customMatCheckContainer">
        <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                    [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
        </mat-checkbox>
    </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="customMatCheckContainer">
        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
        </mat-checkbox>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="displayName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Display Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.displayName}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="userEmail">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Email </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.email}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selection.toggle(row)"></mat-row>
```

### TS

Import the following modules in your module file:
    MatTableModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatSelectModule

You will get all selected entries in 'selection' variable.

```
import { MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';

displayedColumns = ['select', 'displayName', 'userEmail'];
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
selection = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, []);

constructor() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
}

public isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
}

public masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ? this.selection.clear() : this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

more short solution is in your `html`, no need to add `if` and `else` conditions

```
<section *ngFor="let ing of pizzaIng; let i = index" class="example-section">
  <mat-checkbox
     [(ngModel)]="ing.checked">
    {{ing.name}}
  </mat-checkbox>
</section>
  <mat-checkbox 
      class="example-margin"
      [checked]="isAllChecked()" (change)="checkAll()"
      [(ngModel)]="selectAll">
    Select All
  </mat-checkbox>
```

in yout `.ts`

```
isAllChecked() {
    return this.pizzaIng.every(obj => obj.checked);
  }

  checkAll() {
     this.pizzaIng.forEach(obj => obj.checked = this.selectAll);
  }
```

here is a link of working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sahzfe)

Answer (score 0):

For gmail style selection in a datasource, you could divide the entire datasource into chunks of particular size.

```
pageIndex: any = 0;
selectedData: any;

resultArray: any = [];

const result = this.dataSource.data.reduce(
      (resultArray: any, item, index) => {
        const chunkIndex = Math.floor(index / this.pageSize);

        if (!resultArray[chunkIndex]) {
          resultArray[chunkIndex] = []; // start a new chunk
        }

        resultArray[chunkIndex].push(item);

        return resultArray;
      },
      []
    );
this.resultArray = result;
```

Here is the demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jnykdu?file=README.md

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33814001)